# Traversing through a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, traversal

I am trying to figure out how to traverse through a 2D array. The way in which I have been doing it is by using a nested for loop. I am curious to know of any other ways in which this can be done. I just feel like I am repeatedly using nested for loops and would prefer not to.

```
for(int i=0; i<gameBoard.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<gameBoard[i].length; j++) {
}
```

This is the only way in which I know how to access multiple elements within the array. Are there any other ways in which to traverse through multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: What's wrong with the current approach?

Comment: I just feel like I am using it too often and it's making my code really messy. For instance, if I want to use conditional statements on the array, I have to put all of them within the loop.

Comment: This sounds like a problem in the data model. Maybe arrays are not the right fit to model the problem domain?

Comment: No, an array is correct as I need to create a board game and hence the 2D array, but if this is the most efficient way to do them it's fine I guess.

Comment: Why is an array the correct data model for a 2d board game? I'd most probably model it in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're simply looking for alternative ways to process elements within a matrix, just for the sake of knowledge, you could use streams.

Here, I'm using two IntStreams to print a matrix of int. Note that this is definitely not more efficient than the classic nested for approach, it's just an alternative way.

```
int[][] gameboard = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
IntStream.range(0, gameboard.length)
        .boxed()
        .peek(i -> IntStream.range(0, gameboard[i].length)
                .boxed()
                .forEach(j -> System.out.printf("%d ", gameboard[i][j])))
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println());
```

Similarly, the previous code can be recreated also in a form with no indexes.

```
int[][] gameboard = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
Arrays.stream(gameboard)
        .peek(vet -> Arrays.stream(vet)
                .forEach(x -> System.out.printf("%d ", x)))
        .forEach(vet -> System.out.println());
```

### EDIT

Since in the comments I've read that you would like to use a more compact form that also allows you to use conditional statements, then what you're looking for might reinforce the stream approach as you could benefit from the `filter` aggregate operation.

Here, I'm using the previous example to print only even numbers.

```
int[][] gameboard = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
Arrays.stream(gameboard)
        .peek(vet -> Arrays.stream(vet)
                .filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
                .forEach(x -> System.out.printf("%d ", x)))
        .forEach(vet -> System.out.println());
```